# TypeScript: jQuery onClick with eventData

Tags: jquery, typescript, jquery-events

What does the expected handler for a jQuery onclick-event look like in TypeScript which accepts eventData?

A handler without eventData can be defined like this:

```
let onClick(event: JQuery.Event): void
```

which can be registered like this:

```
$("#btn").click(onClick);
```

When registering like this, it works fine in [my test fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/axu20e62/):

```
$("#btn").click("data3", onClick);
```

But my IDE complains:

> Error TS2345  (TS) Argument of type '(event: Event)
>   => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventHandler | EventHandlerBase>'.   Type '(event: Event) => any' is not assignable to type 'EventHandlerBase>'.
>       Types of parameters 'event' and 't' are incompatible.
>         Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'Event'.
>           Type '"data3"' is not assignable to type 'null'.

I understand that in the first case (without eventData), the type of handler is:

```
JQuery.EventHandler<TElement>
```

and in the second case (with eventData):

```
JQuery.EventHandler<TElement, TData>
```

where `TData` is the type of the eventData (string in my example). But how is such an event handler declared using valid and type-safe TypeScript syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the types - of the event target and the event data - as generic attributes to the event:

```
let onClick(event: JQuery.Event<EventTarget, string>): void
```

For the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s70rn9ko/) it makes no difference, but it will make the IDE and yourself happy!

Comment: When I do that it tells me that Type Event is not generic.